# I am installing ELK and I am facing some issues. How do I resolve it?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, elk

I am installing ELK on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM and I am not facing some issues after running the command even after having have done all the necessary changes in the elasticsearch.yml file. Please help me resolve this issue.

Below is the error after runnung the command, **service elasticsearch status**:

```
service elasticsearch status
* elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-11-06 07:36:45 GMT; 1h 37min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 73248 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: You can check the logs[/var/log/elasticsearch] or update them in question as status output mentioned by you is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration changes done to elasticsearch. Service is not able to start due to invalid configuration.